# Is it possible to display External Maven Repository in Drools-KIE web UI?

Tags: java, maven, drools, kie

I have a docker showcase running of drools 7.18.Final

I would like to connect to my external nexus (maven) repo so that I can download the artifact or add it my project.(Using the UI)

Along the way, there is a thread [like](https://groups.google.com/g/drools-setup/c/N_fz0KCtuE4) this which say it is impossible. and article like this which imply it is [doable](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.7/html/installing_and_configuring_red_hat_decision_manager_on_red_hat_jboss_eap_7.2/maven-repo-using-con#maven-external-configure-proc_install-on-eap)

My approach is:

- Create settings.xml point to my external nexus
- Add `<property name="kie.maven.settings.custom" value="/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/settings.xml"/>` to the standalone-full-drools.xml
- If added an settings.xml to .m2 folder, an error will be shown

The above approach is not working but I just want to make sure it is even possible before trying further